# Fix all "Unit of measure is redundant" occurrences

Tags: css, resharper, legacy-code

Using Resharper 8.0.1 I have scanned a large legacy solution for redundant units of measurement (e.g. 0px) by using the "Find all issues of this type in scope..." option.

This is finding over 12000 instances, however I can't see a way to fix them all en-mass.

The ["Code Cleanup"](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Cleanup_Settings.html) option doesn't seem to include this warning in its "Remove Code Redundancies" option.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm in similar position, sadly there doesn't seem to be an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Now in the year 2020, there certainly is an easy way to do this.  And since this seems to be the main result that comes up when Googling for this answer, here is a solution:

1. Install NodeJS

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

2. Install StyleLint:

   npm install --save-dev stylelint stylelint-config-standard

Then on the command line interface... for example, to fix all css files in the current directory:

```
stylelint "*.css" --fix
```

You can easily customize StyleLint to only look for and fix certain style issues, per your preference. Detailed instructions are available here:

https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/get-started.md

https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/options#fix